# How can I have a terminal window persist beyond the script it was opened for? (NOT just "keep the window open" or start a new shell)

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

I am not especially tied to using a shell script for this purpose, but my requirements are as follows:

- I can double-click an icon on my desktop. (This is intended to select an *optional, alternate* way of starting up a terminal window; so I **can not** simply edit a `.bashrc`, `.profile` etc.)
- This causes a terminal window to open, and some commands to run, including another script. (Per documentation, this one **must** be `source`d from Bash.)
- After the commands run, the window stays open *indefinitely, usable to input more shell commands*. (This means that anything based on `read`, `xterm -keep` etc. is **not** a solution.)
- The commands that have run *impact the state of the shell*. (This is why I have a question to ask here.)

The specific use case is that I want to open a window, start in a particular directory (in my case, a folder on the desktop which holds subdirectories for Python projects I'm working on), and have a Python virtual environment activated (in my case, a common "scratch" venv named `SANDBOX` located directly in that directory).

After much research, I eventually ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/dev
source SANDBOX/bin/activate
exec $SHELL
```

This is *almost* right. It's good enough that I could live with it if I really had to, but I'm really bothered by the shortcomings. In my testing, the window stays open and is usable; the pwd is set properly; and the `VIRTUALENV` and `PATH` environment variables are properly modified by the script. However, `PS1` does not get set, the prompt is therefore not modified, and the `deactivate` command does not become available as it normally would.

How can I make this properly transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Credit

Kamil's answer worked well for me, but it turns out I had some minor additional requirements that I didn't realize until I saw the answer. I managed to solve the problem completely in a different way, with this new understanding.

### Discussion

In my case, I really do not want to modify the custom script because it is generated by Python. (In the more general case, I also want to be able to run the script without reloading .bashrc.) I also didn't want to write a separate custom rcfile because it doesn't feel scalable; now I am making *two* special files each time I want this kind of wrapper (and I expect to want it for a few other things).

The issues seem to result from start a new shell, even with `exec` rather than as a command. While it does properly manage the lifetime of the window,

- the .bashrc gets run again, overriding the setting for `PS1`;
- function definitions aren't exported, so the new shell simply doesn't have it.

The first issue can't really be solved by using `exec bash --norc`, because I want the modifications to `PS1` from both places - just in the other order. The second issue isn't addressed at all that way.

The trick to making the original approach work is that the `activate` script has to run in the *last* shell created (however many there happen to be). That shell needs to, by some method, run .bashrc, and then the original script contents. But... if we aren't going to modify the original (to source .bashrc first; and aren't going to make a separate script wrapper (to run both in order); and aren't going to just `bash -c` them both in order (that doesn't work; we need `-c` in order to arrange that, but then we don't get a persistent terminal) - what do we do?

### My Solution

What I came up with is: *invert the logic, and make `.bashrc` (conditionally) source the new script*. Since we can't pass it command-line parameters (they would go to the `bash` invocation without `-c`, and with `-c` we again don't get a persistent terminal), we pass the necessary information by setting up an environment variable. To do that, we need an outer, wrapping subshell.

I added the following to the end of `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f "$MORE_STARTUP" ]; then
    . $MORE_STARTUP
elif [ -n "$MORE_STARTUP" ]; then
    echo "Warning! Could not run ${MORE_STARTUP}"
fi
```

Now the `MORE_STARTUP` environment variable, if set and found, specifies a script with additional setup actions to take. It *can* be set from an ordinary script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/start/dir
export MORE_STARTUP=path/to/script
exec bash
```

However, this still leaves Cinnamon's warning about executing text files, and the "Run in Terminal" option is necessary to make it work. That's still a touch awkward. Instead, following the original advice, I make a launcher shaped like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/bin/bash -c "export MORE_STARTUP=\"path/to/script\" && /bin/bash"
Icon=some-icon
Name=custom terminal
Path=/path/to/start/dir
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

I found that shell expansion does not work in the `Path` option. It should also work to add a `cd` to the command sequence, but using `Path` still seems cleaner. The escaped quotes are not necessary here, but would be if the path had a space etc. in it.

Now there is just one wrapper per original script, and it double-clicks directly to do everything I want. I even started working on a script to generate such launchers (adding a function to `.bashrc` proved unwieldy, so I'll use Python instead).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Create a shortcut (a [`.desktop` file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries) or whatever) that can run a command in a terminal emulator. The command should be:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile /path/to/rcfile
```

where `rcfile` is a custom file that will be [sourced by `bash` in place of `~/.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files)*. In the file do source what you want, call `cd` or whatever. You probably want to source `~/.bashrc` anyway, so do it explicitly in the custom file. *Do not spawn another `bash`*.

<sup>* [Some distros ship `bash` that sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/815083/693277), then with `--rcfile` you replace them both with a single custom file. Adjust the rest of the answer if needed.</sup>

---

#### Proof of concept

This is my example `customshell.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Exec=/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.myspecialbashrc
Icon=utilities-terminal
Name=My custom shell
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

And `~/.myspecialbashrc` is:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
cd ~/Desktop/dev
. SANDBOX/bin/activate
```

I tested with a simple `activate` file that sets a shell variable and some shell options. It worked, the interactive shell I got was configured exactly as planned.

---

#### Simplification

The setup sources `~/Desktop/dev/SANDBOX/bin/activate` eventually. If you don't mind putting additional things in the `activate` file then you don't need any additional rcfile (like `~/.myspecialbashrc` above). The desktop file will be like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Exec=/bin/bash --rcfile SANDBOX/bin/activate
Icon=utilities-terminal
Name=My custom shell
Path=~/Desktop/dev
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
```

Note `Path=~/Desktop/dev` is responsible for entering the right directory before `bash` even starts, so we don't need to `cd` later (i.e. in the `activate` file). Still, if you want to source `~/.bashrc` then you need to source it from within the `activate` file.

If you cannot or don't want to alter the `activate` file then stick to the first solution (with `~/.myspecialbashrc`; note `Path=~/Desktop/dev` instead of `cd` is still an option). It would be nice if you could make `bash` source many files in sequence by providing more than one `--rcfile` in the command line (`bash --rcfile … --rcfile …`); in my tests this doesn't work though, only the last `--rcfile` takes effect.

Comment: Did you test this specifically with a) modifying the `PS1` variable; b) defining a function for use in the later shell? It did work for me, though. I think the problem with `PS1` for me is that it also gets set in my .bashrc (so `exec bash` would replace it again). I made some enhancements and will write and accept my own answer, but thank you very  much for the insight.